# How to find Intrumentation in Monetdb

Tags: instrumentation, execution-time, monetdb, monetdb-assembly-language

How can I get instumemtation in monetdb ? I need thedetails like  planning time , execution time for each MAL statement in monetdb . Is there any command for it ?

Answer (score 0):

The planning time is reported in the Default branch as part of the EXPLAIN.
For all branches you can use sys.querylog_catalog() to see compilation times.
The individual MAL instruction timing can be observed with the TRACE modifier:
For more information see:https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipes/QueryTiming